Need help identifying this SMD part please
This is from a VP7-3ATI LCD Controller from Westar. The reference for the part on the board is U31
The best I can tell is the text on the chip says either "B7AK" or "87AK" but I'm not sure. I couldn't find the part number in Westar's documentation and have not had very much luck with googling the markings. Any ideas would be awesome, thanks!

It's an onsemi (formerly Fairchild) NC7SB3157P6X (aka FSA3157P6X) SPDT analog switch.


(Source: lcsc.com)
